# Nginx server does not load css files from skeleton framework

Tags: html, css, nginx, config, skeleton-css-boilerplate

**Hey there,**

I'm new when dealing with NIGNX servers and Linux. My HTML file is displayed but my server does not load the CSS files.

The only thing I found was this line 
`include /etc/nginx/mime.types;`
which I include in the http block.

After that I reload my config with `sudo nginx -s reload`. To be sure I also executed `sudo nginx -s stop` and `sudo nginx`.

This is my whole config:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {

        location / {
            root /data/www;
        }

        location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
            root /data/www/images;
        }
    }
}

events {}
```

My skeleton files are located in /data/www. In this directory there is another CSS folder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you tail your log? ( generally /var/log/nginx/access.log and error.log by default)

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions on the css folder?

Comment: my permission on the css folder is that one: drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Feb  5 04:04 css .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're going to need to tell NGINX to have your static files to obtain a TTL (time to live) via expire headers. Locate this in your NGINX configuration file, if it isn't there. Create a new directive with `location`

```
location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 1s;
}
```

After this go ahead and purge your files from the server and force it to serve new files.

- Set sendfile off in `nginx.conf`
- Set expires 1s in `mysite.conf`
- Explicitly set Cache-Control header: `add_header Cache-Control no-cache;`

---

Of course, before doing anything above. If it doesn't require drastic measure, try manually deleting everything in the cache folder: `/var/cache/nginx`

If that doesn't help then proceed with everything listed here!

---

After you've successfully purged your server from serving static files. Add this to your NGINX server block to achieve optimization.

```
gzip             on;
gzip_comp_level  2;
gzip_min_length  1000;
gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/xml;
```

It's possible to set expire headers for files that don't change and are served regularly.

```
location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 365d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I will try your instructions :)